# JQuery mouseenter fire more than once on overlapping divs

Tags: jquery

I am using JQuery mouseenter event to show a div inside another div. When the mouse enters DIV A I show a smaller DIV B inside it. The problem is that when I put my mouse over DIV B, JQuery runs the mouseenter event again. I want to show DIV B (inner one) and when the mouse goes over it, not to fire the mouseenter event again. Although technically, my mouse is still hovering DIV A. So on other words, Mouseout over DIV B causes JQuery to run mouseenter on DIV A again, that what I understand.

[image]

Code:

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".si", function (e) {
   settingsIcon(e,1);

});

$()

$(document).on("mouseout", ".si", function (e) {
    settingsIcon(e,0);

});

function settingsIcon(e, action) {

 if (action === 1) // show
{
    $(".settings_icon").remove();
    var id = parseInt(e.target.id.replace("dvci_", ""), 10); 
    $("#dvc_" + id).prepend("<div class='settings_icon' ><img class='settings_icon_image' src='settings.png' style='width:59px; height:57px'  /></div>");
    var icon = $("#dvc_" + id + " .settings_icon");

    icon.css({
        "left": ($("#dvci_" + id).width() / 2) - 30,
        "top": parseInt($("#dvci_" + id).css("margin-top").replace("px", ""), 10) + ($("#dvci_" + id).height() / 2) - 30
    });

    $(".settings_icon img").show("scale", {}, 400);

}
else {
    // hide
    $(".settings_icon").remove();
}
}
```

**jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/tLUrd/

Comment: Post your jquery code as well. And look at event.stopPropagation();

Comment: I've added the code as you asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using [**event.stopPropagation()**](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/):

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".si", function (e) {
   settingsIcon(e,1);
});

$(document).on("mouseleave", ".si", function (e) {
    settingsIcon(e,0);
});

$(document).on("mouseenter", "#b", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).on("mouseleave", "#b", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: I've added the code to the question. I've tried what you shown but it seems not to work.

Comment: Tried it and it didn't work :(. When I put my mouse over DIV B it hides it, which it shouldn't, only when I leave DIV A itself.

Comment: Works without the stopPropagation, unless I'm going mad

Comment: yes it works without, strange things are going with this code lol

Answer (score 0):

```
$("selector").hover(
  function () {
    console.log("mouse in");
  },
  function () {
    console.log("mouse out");
  }
);
```

http://api.jquery.com/hover/

jQuery.hover() won't fire for children elements, just for the element it is bound to, thus solving your issues. I've had this a few times before as well, .hover() really does the trick.

Comment: Can you provide an example for the code. The inner div is generated dynamically.  I did use hover instead of mouseenter, but it result in the same problem ( hover: function (e) { settingsIcon(e, 1); },). The problem is with the mouseleave function. When I am on the DIV B, it fires mouseleave for DIV A

Answer (score -1):

jQuery .hover() takes up to two parameters:

```
$("#a").hover(
    function () { settingsIcon(null, 1); },
    function () { settingsIcon(null, 0); }
);
```

**Edit:**

To avoid rebinding the above event if you dynamically generate #a:

```
$(document).on( {
    mouseenter: function() { settingsIcon(null, 1); },
    mouseleave: function() { settingsIcon(null, 0); }
}, '#a');
```

Comment: The Divs are added dynamically so it won't work, any way to change the above code to match dynamically added elements so I can check that?. Thanks